# UIViewController difficulty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

//RootViewViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "OneSlotViewController.h"
#import "TwoSlotViewController.h"
#import "BingoSlotViewController.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface RootViewViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIButton *owaru;
    OneSlotViewController *oneSlotViewController;
    TwoSlotViewController *button2ViewController;
    BingoSlotViewController *button3ViewController;
    UIViewController *pushedController;
    UIButton *hajimekara;
    SettingsViewController *settingsVc;


}
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *hajimekara;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *owaru;
@property (nonatomic, retain) OneSlotViewController *button1ViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TwoSlotViewController *button2ViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BingoSlotViewController *button3ViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *pushedController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SettingsViewController *settingsVc;
```

//RootViewViewController.m

```
@synthesize button1ViewController;
@synthesize button2ViewController;
@synthesize button3ViewController;
@synthesize pushedController;
@synthesize settingsVc;


-(IBAction) startButtonPressed:(id) sender { 
    if (self.settingsVc.pushedController!=nil) { 
        NSLog(@"push"); 
        [self presentViewController:self.settingsVc.pushedController animated:YES completion:NULL]; 
    } 
}
```

//SettingViewController.h

```
#import "OneSlotViewController.h"
#import "TwoSlotViewController.h"
#import "BingoSlotViewController.h"

#import "SettingsViewController.h"

#import "AGImagePickerController.h"


@class RootViewViewController;


@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>{


    OneSlotViewController *oneSlotViewController;
    TwoSlotViewController *button2ViewController;
    BingoSlotViewController *button3ViewController;
    UIViewController *pushedController;
     RootViewViewController *mainVc;
    UIImageView *lastPriceView;
    CustomImagePicker *_imagePicker;
    UINavigationController *navController;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) OneSlotViewController *button1ViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TwoSlotViewController *button2ViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BingoSlotViewController *button3ViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *pushedController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewViewController *mainVc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *lastPriceView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomImagePicker *imagePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
```

//SettingViewController.m

```
-(IBAction) button1Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.button1ViewController==nil) {
        button1ViewController = [[OneSlotViewController alloc] init];
    }
    self.pushedController = button1ViewController;
}

-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.button2ViewController==nil) {
        button2ViewController = [[TwoSlotViewController alloc] init];
    }
    self.pushedController = button2ViewController;
}

-(IBAction) button3Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.button3ViewController==nil) {
        button3ViewController = [[BingoSlotViewController alloc] init];
    }
    self.pushedController = button3ViewController;
}
```

I have already declare there instances un the two controllers.
Whenever a button is pressed in the SettingsViewController it will pass the ViewController to the MainViewController's startButton.
But I cant seem to make it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @geon have added the question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SettingsViewController.pushedController and MainViewController.pushedController are separate variables. Changing one will not effect the other.

You have two options. You either need to store the SettingsViewController in the MainViewController, or pass the MainViewController to SettingsViewController.

If MainViewController keeps a reference to the SettingsViewController, then you can:

```
-(IBAction) startButtonPressed:(id) sender { 
    if (self.settingsViewController.pushedController!=nil) { 
        NSLog(@"push"); 
        [self presentViewController:self.settingsViewController.pushedController animated:YES completion:NULL]; 
    } 
}
```

If SettingsViewController is passed a reference to MainViewController, then you can:

```
-(IBAction) button1Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.button1ViewController==nil) {
        button1ViewController = [[ViewOneController alloc] init];
    }
    self.mainViewController.pushedController = button1ViewController;
}

-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.button2ViewController==nil) {
        button2ViewController = [[ViewTwoController alloc] init];
    }
    self.mainViewController.pushedController = button2ViewController;
}

-(IBAction) button3Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.button3ViewController==nil) {
        button3ViewController = [[ViewThreeController alloc] init];
    }
    self.mainViewController.pushedController = button3ViewController;
}
```

Pick one of these things and you should be OK.

Comment: my main view is my root view. can't instantiate it

Comment: You don't need to instantiate one from the other, you just need to connect the two. Use interface builder, use the app delegate, or some other point. There has to be a way for you to link the two together.

Comment: Could you post the new code including how you connected MainViewController and SettingsViewController?

Comment: How are you setting `self.settingsVc` in RootViewViewController?

Comment: I dont know. I just imported then. Connect them to each other. Why?

Comment: In RootViewViewController, `@property (nonatomic, retain) SettingsViewController *settingsVc;` is not an IBOutlet. It will not get set in Interface Builder. What is the code that has `self. settingsVc = ...`?

Comment: Sorry, "The startbutton,." does not mean anything to me. You need to connect the instance of MainViewController to the instance of SettingsViewController. If you cannot do that, I really cannot be of much help.